# Postgres JSONB query simplification

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have some working code which pulls records from a forms table where 'mail@example.com' appears as a JSON value in one of the JSONB fields,`column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`, or `column_d`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM forms f
WHERE exists (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_a) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com')   
UNION

SELECT * 
FROM forms f
WHERE exists (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_b) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com')
UNION

SELECT * 
FROM forms f
WHERE exists (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_c) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com')
UNION

SELECT * 
FROM forms f
WHERE exists (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_d) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com');
```

The JSON in the columns is similar to:

```
{ "xyz":"mail@example.com", "def":"mail2@example.com", "lmn":"mail3@example.com" }
```

Although the code works, it looks highly repetitive/long-winded. Given that I can't change the JSON structure, is there are more concise way of building this query, and what indexes should I be building for those columns for the best performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `or`?

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM forms f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_a) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_b) as e(ky,val)
              WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com'
             ) OR
      . . .
```

Presumably, this also eliminates the need for duplicate elimination, so the query should be faster as well.

EDIT:

If you want the sources, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_a) as e(ky,val)
                     WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com'
                    ) as in_column_a,
             EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM jsonb_each_text(f.column_b) as e(ky,val)
                     WHERE e.val = 'mail@example.com'
                    ) as in_column_b,
             . . .
      FROM forms f
     ) 
WHERE in_column_a OR in_column_b OR . . .
```

This is not quite as efficient, because it does not short-circuit the evaluation when it finds a match.  On the other hand, it lists all columns that have a match.

Comment: Yes, good point. I simplified the original which had a `SELECT roletype='blah', * ` at the start of each sub-query - so that the source column can be differentiated. But the result seet should be quite small, so I should be iterate over them in the requesting code (NodeJS).

Comment: Nice. But I think I prefer your option 1 and do the munging post fetch. Thanks for the insight though :-)